# Differential Equation System Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$(D^2 -9D)y=3x^2$

$D(D-9)=0$

$D=0 \ \mathbb or D=9$

$y_H = c_{1}e^0+c_{2}e^{9x} $

$y_S = \frac{1}{(D^2-9D)}3x^2 = (\frac{A}{D}+\frac{B}{D-9}) 3x^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{D(D-9)} = \frac{A}{D} + \frac{B}{D-9},  A=\frac{-1}{9}, B= \frac{1}{9} $

Couldn't get the general solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

$$(D^2 -9D)y_p=3x^2$$
Integrate:
$$(D -9)y_p=x^3$$
$$y_p=\dfrac 1{(D-9)}x^3$$
$$y_p=-\dfrac 19 \dfrac 1{(1-D/9)}x^3$$
$$y_p=-\dfrac 19 \left(1+D/9+D^2/9^2+D^3/9^3+...\right)x^3$$
$$y_p=-\dfrac 19 \left (x^3+\dfrac {x^2}{3}+\dfrac {2x}{27} \right)$$
The constant is absorbed by the solution to the homogeneous differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$\bullet \ \dfrac{1}{D}(3x^2) \equiv\int3x^2dx$
$\bullet \ \dfrac{1}{D-9}(3x^2) = \dfrac{-1}{9}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{D}{9}}(3x^2) = -\dfrac{1}{3}\left(1+\dfrac{D}{9}+\left(\dfrac{D}{9}\right)^2+\cdots\right)x^2$